# WCF client exception: Unrecognized message version

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I hit this error today when deploying a WCF client to QA:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Unrecognized message version.

In Fiddler I noticed that the WCF client sends its request wrapped in a SOAP Envelope (as expected) but that the response from the remote web service is not wrapped in a SOAP Envelope. That is, our local debug web service sends a response like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Response xmlns="urn:example">
      <Success>true</Success>
      ...
    </Response>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But the remote web service is just sending this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ns0:Response xmlns:ns0="urn:example">
  <ns0:Success>true</ns0:Success>
  ...
</ns0:Response>
```

As far as I can tell the WCF client is throwing the exception because there's no SOAP Envelope. So my questions are:

1. Is my assumption correct or should be I looking elsewhere?
2. Is there some way to configure the WCF client's bindings to remove the SOAP Envelope expectation?
3. Should I just tell the remote service implementor to fix their service (which they wrote just for us from a supplied WSDL)?

The WCF client is using basicHttpBindings (and HTTP Basic Authentication over SSL/TLS). I'd considered using IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply() to rewrite the response but the exception gets thrown before that method is invoked, i.e.: We already have an implementation of it for request/response logging and it's not hitting a breakpoint in there.

---

More info:

After communicating with the service developer it sounds like they completely ignored the .wsdl and (svcutil generated) IService.cs files we gave them and wrote a POX (Plain-Old XML) service from scratch.

I'm not confident that we can convince them to do it properly, so now I'm looking for tips to convert a properly behaving WCF SOAP client into a POX client.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by that your service uses Soap1.2 while you are using a different version to call it.

Please try "Add Service Reference" - "Advanced..." - "Add Web Reference..." as a compatibility approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. I know this is an older post, but in my case I modified the `app.config` file in my C# .NET app that calls this web service. I think it was adding

```
<security mode="Transport" />
```

to the `basicHttpBinding` element that solved it. I also extended the timeouts and `maxBufferPoolSize`.

Microsoft has [documentation that describes this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-set-the-security-mode), in case this helps someone else.